# Is it possible to execute a specific block of code before the OnPost() method is executed in the .cshtml.cs file on a set pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a good number of pages I want to determine whether I should allow the `OnPost()` to be executed.

I was wondering if you can/what the best way of executing a block of code before the `OnPost()` takes place to potentially block the `OnPost()` call is?

I know you could do a check at the top of every `OnPost()` and call some object/class method to dictate but is there some other way that would execute before the `OnPost()` is even executed for a specific set of pages?

(Using Razor Pages, not MVC)

Comment: What you are looking for is called Middleware, where you can insert functionality into the processing pipeline, see https://www.learnrazorpages.com/middleware for an example

Comment: If this is about whether or not to allow access, I would suggest you to use the built-in authorization stack to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Filter to execute code after the handler method has been selected, but before it has been executed:

```
public override void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
{
    if(context.HandlerMethod.MethodInfo.Name == nameof(OnPost))
    {
        // code placed here will only execute if the OnPost() method has been selected
    }
}
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters